# Getting error requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool raise ProxyError(e, request=request)

Tags: python, https, python-requests

When i try to run a sample script which sends SOAP request to a HTTPS URL getting below error `

```
File "H:/PyCharm/Sample.py", line 94, in <module>
response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 110, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in     request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 485, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=    <myhost>,port=443)Max retries exceeded with url: <myurl>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use requests or urllib3 or SOAPpy to send SOAP to HTTPS. PycURL came to the rescue. I was able to do with a 5 line pyCURL implementation.